# Which kinds of Physics laws do and don't comply with the principle of relativity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, symmetry, relativity

In Physics, the principle of relativity is the requirement that the equations describing the laws of physics have the same form in all admissible frames of reference.

However, according to [this](http://www.loreto.unican.es/Carpeta2012/EJP%28Mungan%29Bernoulli%282011%29.pdf) and [this](http://www.physics.princeton.edu/~mcdonald/examples/bernoulli.pdf) paper, it seems Bernoulli's Equation is a frame-dependent example in both Newtonian and relativistic mechanics.

**Which kinds of laws are frame-independent and which are not?**

Comment: What do you mean by 'kind of law'? Bernoulli's Equation isn't a law -- it's a simplification of the Euler equations under isentropic conditions.

Comment: @tpg2114 In my view, law is theorem in the theory of nature. Besides, in wikipedia  it said Bernoulli's Equation described [Bernoulli's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle)...

Comment: I am familiar with it. It is not a law. At best it is a corollary. Regardless, I don't understand what you mean by "kind of law". Are you looking for a specific list of physical laws that are not frame-independent?

Comment: @tpg2114 What I mean is to ask properties which exactly frame-independent equations hold but frame-dependent equations not.

Comment: So your question is more "What makes a law frame independent?" I am really unclear on your question as it is written.

Comment: @tpg2114 The second paper I cited said "The general answer is NO, in that some 'laws' involve special constraints that are valid
only in a particular frame". So "involve special constraints" seems a character that some frame-dependent equations have.

Comment: Again -- do you mean to ask "What makes a law frame-independent?" By asking "What kinds of laws" implies you are looking for either a list of frame-dependent laws or something more vague like "Conservation" which also doesn't make sense. If you are interested in what constraints make something frame-dependent, you really need to re-write your question to clarify that.

Comment: @tpg2114 Well, I don't think there is any ambiguous. If asked which kind of natural number cannot be divided by any natural number other than 1 and itself, the answer is 1 or prime numbers. Similarly, my question is to ask which kind of physics equations is not invariant via frame transformation? Example answer is like 'the equitions have ineliminable constant which is not invariant via frame transformation'.

Comment: I think that the misunderstanding comes from the use of "law" in your question. A law in my vocabulary is "conservation of energy",etc. In this day and age in physics laws are called, by definition, those that ARE CONSISTENT with special relativity. All previous formulations, in Newtonian for example, that might have  been  called laws in the nineteenth century are out of date in physics as we know it presently.

Comment: Hmm, this is rather open-ended, I'm closing it as Not Constructive. If you can make it more specific (not asking for a general list), I'd be happy to reopen :)

Comment: @Popopo: we have never found a system that does not respect (local) Lorentz invariance. The examples you mention appear not to respect it but as the papers describe, if you look more closely the apparent failure of invarience is due to approximations being made that aren't valid. If you're interested in what might cause a failure of Lorentz invarience have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_covariance#Lorentz_violating_models where various possibilities are discussed. Incidentally I think your quuestion has been unfairly closed so I've upvoted it and flagged it to be reopened.

Comment: @JohnRennie: Oops. I read this as "which law of physics" (narq) and not "which kind of law" (perfectly OK, and a good question imho). Reopened, thanks for noticing :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All basic laws of physics are frame-independent. They either exhibit Galilean (non-relativistic) or Lorentzian (relativistic) invariance. Examples are Newton's laws (Galilean), Maxwell's equations (Lorentzian), Navier-Stokes equations (Galilean), etc. A notable exception is formed by Schrödinger's equation which, [upon closer inspection](http://redshift.vif.com/JournalFiles/V13NO4PDF/V13N4OST.pdf), can be fixed into being Lorentz invariant under transformations up to first order in $v/c$.

Phenomenological laws and laws derived from the basic laws if physics often fail to be frame-independent. Such instances of frame-dependence occur when specific assumptions are made that single out a specific frame of reference. The Bernouilli equation being an example as it is derived under the assumption that a reference frame is chosen in which the fluid flow is stationary. Another example is given by the diffusion equation, the derivation of which assumes a reference frame can be found in which convection is absent.

Comment: it's not true that they either exhibit Galilean or Lorentzian invariance, they all obey the latter. Galilean invariance is an approximation for v<<c

Comment: these are two distinct symmetries which become indistinguishable in the limit $v/c -> 0$.

Comment: Yes, I can see that you're right now.